# How to center map in PageLayoutControl?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine

In my print preview dialog I have a `PageLayoutControl` loading the same map as the main view's `MapControl`. I want the map in the `PageLayoutControl` to center at the same position as the `MapControl`. Using `Extent` is not a solution because the `PageLayoutControl` has a fixed ratio (square). (I tried using the same extent, but it didn't work at all.)

I tried the following, but `CenterAt()` didn't do the trick.

```
  IEnvelope extent = _mapControl.Extent;
  double lXMin, lXMax, lYMin, lYMax;
  lXMin = extent.XMin;
  lXMax = extent.XMax;
  lYMin = extent.YMin;
  lYMax = extent.YMax;

  IPoint centerPoint = new PointClass();
  centerPoint.SpatialReference = _mapControl.SpatialReference;
  centerPoint.X = lXMin + ((lXMax - lXMin) / 2);
  centerPoint.Y = lYMin + ((lYMax - lYMin) / 2);
  _pageLayoutControl.CenterAt(centerPoint);
```

Neither did `Extent.CenterAt()` help:

```
 _pageLayoutControl.Extent.CenterAt(centerPoint);
```

I don't have MapServer, so I can't use `ICenterAndScale`. I didn't find a `MapDescription` in the `PageLayoutControl` at all.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following when you switch from the MapControl to the PageLayoutControl or when you show the PageLayout. The application I tested on was using a tab control so...

```
private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.TabPageIndex == 1)
    {
        IPageLayout pageLayout = (IPageLayout)axPageLayoutControl1.ActiveView;
        syncExtent(pageLayout, (IEnvelope)axMapControl1.ActiveView.Extent);
    }
}

private void syncExtent(IPageLayout pageLayout, IEnvelope env)
{
    IGraphicsContainer graphicsContainer = (IGraphicsContainer)pageLayout;
    graphicsContainer.Reset();
    IElement element = graphicsContainer.Next();
    while (element != null)
    {
        if (element is IMapFrame)
        {
            IMapFrame mapFrame = (IMapFrame)element;
            IActiveView tmpActiveView = (IActiveView)mapFrame.Map;
            tmpActiveView.Extent = env;
        }
        element = graphicsContainer.Next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need close integration between the MapControl and PagelayoutControl you should look at the sample in Concept & Samples section in the documentation, See [How to synchronize the MapControl and PageLayoutControl](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_synchronize_the_MapControl_and_PageLayoutControl/000100000153000000/)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but I had problems on resetting the `MapControl.Map` back to it's initial state, when the user changed something (extent, scale...) in the print preview's `PageLayoutControl`.